# Getting this error while hitting discovery.svc in browser

Tags: content-delivery, discovery-service, tridion-sites

I am trying to install Discovery Service. After running installService.ps1 does I'm trying to hit localhost:8082/discovery.svc its showing as follows.

[image]

**Log file**

[image]

**Am I missing something or are there more steps?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means you're not passing correct credentials to the service (which would be the case when just using a browser).

The security configuration for the discovery service is [described in the documentation](https://docs.rws.com/986894/509237/tridion-sites-9-6-main-documentation/configuring-the-passwords-of-------------content-delivery-user-accounts). IIRC, you can *disable* authentication to this service, which would allow you to call it from a browser, but **OBVIOUSLY** this is not recommended in production.

Alternatively, check this guide on how to configure PostMan to talk to Tridion Microservices: https://velmuruganarjunan.wordpress.com/2017/09/02/using-postman-to-explore-sdl-restful-microservices/

Comment: Another alternative is to use the PowerShell. Example code can be found here: https://github.com/TridionPractice/tridion-practice/wiki/DiscoverEnvironmentCapabilities